# (VBA EXCEL) Replace only 0 with four spaces

Tags: vba, excel, replace, null, isnullorempty

This is an oddly specific question. Suppose I had a cell that yields a value of 0. I am writing it to a text file.

When I write it instead of 0 I want there to be four spaces (it is essentially a visual placeholder for null).

Problem with this line:

```
cellValue = Replace(cellValue, 0, "    ")
```

This tends to replace ALL zeroes with four spaces. Does anybody have a clue as to how to solve this? I would appreciate any and all help.

Sample input:

```
0 | 100 | 48
```

Sample Output:

```
____10048 (Underscores are spaces).
```

What I have so far:

```
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, I As Integer, j As Integer

myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\test_data_output.txt"
Set rng = Selection
Open myFile For Output As #1                                    

For I = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
cellValue = Replace(cellValue, 0, "    ")
cellValue = cellValue + CStr(rng.Cells(I, j).Value)
If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Print #1, cellValue
End If

    Next j
    cellValue = ""
Next I

Close #1
```

---------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------

So we just decided to do a excel sheet if isBLANK condition to show 4 spaces if its false. That should work for now. Thanks for all the help. It was essentially a blank set of cells that was carried on to a new sheet. Thus for some reason it always showed 0 to show that its blank. We decided the if else would be best.

Excel Code:

```
=IF(ISBLANK('OurSheetName'!I7),"    ",'OurSheetName'!I8)
```

Comment: Match entire cell contents? Is that a command?

Comment: 0 | 100 | 48  -  is this exactly the data in your cell?

Comment: Yeah the "|" are to show three different cells with those three numbers.

Comment: You can use the Match Entire Cell Contents, it would look something like this:  `YourRange.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="    ", LookAt:=xlWhole`

Comment: So this is really good because it does sort of what I want. It does find and replace the 0, BUT it replaces all ZEROS. So 0 becomes four space, BUT 100 becomes 1________ which is not what I wanted.

Comment: If you have a solution you should accept one of the answers, or post your own solution as an answer and then accept it. This is  how questions are closed on Stack Overflow. Just updating the question to say you have a solution does not record the problem as solved.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues with your code:-

1. You have defined `cellValue` as a `Variant` for no apparent reason. You are always better to declare variables using a datatype that best represents the data. You could simply declare it as a `String` unless you have a very good reason to keep it as an expensive-to-use `Variant`.
2. I can't see where you are assigning a value to `cellValue`. Is this the complete code or have you edited it for posting?  It is difficult to assess code if it has been hacked for posting without proper comments to explain what was removed.

You could simply test the value before writing it:-

```
...

'Inside the "For j" loop

cellValue = rng.Value

'Test the value - but test it as a string value
If cellValue = "0" Then
  cellValue = "    "     'Replace with 4 spaces
End If

'Carry on with code...
```

Comment: Oh wow ur right I totally forgot to include this line: cellValue = cellValue + CStr(rng.Cells(I, j).Value)  For some reason The If cellValue Statement = is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Before making the replacement, just check if the cell value is 0.

```
For I = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
  For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    If cellValue = 0 Then
       cellValue = Replace(cellValue, 0, "    ")
    End If
    If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
       Print #1, cellValue
    End If
  Next j
  cellValue = ""
Next I
```